# All pairwise differences between two vectors

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors:

```
X1 <- c(44350, 38920, 37530, 42280, 37320, 36910, 35720, 31220, 33400, 40710, 43830, 37390, 32340, 30770, 35800, 40250, 31490, 40460, 33730, 35850, 35320, 37500, 35380, 40910, 29040, 33950)

X2 <- c(30390, 34170, 28910, 30660, 32510, 30540, 31990, 32380, 32110, 31260, 34670, 28240, 31840, 33350, 32150, 35640, 30730, 30280, 29420, 30990, 32880, 33280, 36960, 36990)
```

I am interested in counting all pairwise instances where a member of X1 < member of X2.

How would I do this in R for any two vectors?

Now, suppose I wish to combine both vectors, randomize, split into two vectors of length(X1) and length(X2) then count as above--creating a randomized distribution to compare against the initial count.

How would this be done?

Comment: `all_pairs = expand.grid(X1 = X1, X2 = X2)` should get you started.

Comment: Because of vectorization `X1 < X2` will evaluate pairwise

Comment: As for your second question, what have you tried and where are you stuck? Do you not know how to combine vectors? Try the `c()` function. Can you randomize vector? Search SO for "r random order". Do you not know how to subset? Read an introduction tor R...

Comment: It depends a little what you mean by `pairwise`. In R, it usually means comparing two vectors of equal length by element position (`pmax` and `pmin`), but your vectors are not of equal length at the moment. If you mean all possible combinations, Gregor's `expand.grid` above will help. For part 2, combine with `c`, shuffle with `sample`, and subset with `[`.

Comment: Did you intend to create an example with vectors of unequal length? If yes, specify what you mean by pairwise when one vector runs out

Comment: Yes, I meant to have vectors of unequal length. I think I figured out how to do this from doing some more reading:

    'foo <- function(datin, len1, i){
    datout <- datin[i]
    vec1 <- datout[1:len1]
    vec2 <- datout[(len1+1):length(datout)]
    bigs <- sum((-0.5*sign(as.vector(outer(vec1,vec2,"-"))))+0.5)
    bigs
    }'

The datin would be both vectors concatenated. Len1 would be the length of the first vector. Then I could bootstrap and use the $t as my distribution. The responses here did get me thinking, so thanks for jiggling my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Count of instances where a in X1 and b in X2 with a < b

```
(s <- sum(outer(X1,X2,`<`)))
# [1] 106
```

---

Combine the two

```
X <- c(X1,X2)
```

Shuffle, resplit, and retest many times

```
set.seed(1)

r <- replicate(1000000, {
  X <- sample(X)
  X1 <- head(X,length(X1)) 
  X2 <- tail(X,length(X2))
  sum(outer(X1,X2,`<`)) })

(p <- 1 - sum(s <= r)/length(r))
# [1] 1e-05
```

---

Note: It sounds like you might be looking for something like the Mann-Whitney test, which is under `wilcox.test`.

```
> wilcox.test(X2,X1)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  X2 and X1
W = 106, p-value = 2.858e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Compare `W = 106` to `s = 106` above.

Comment: Not the Wilcoxon test, since the vectors are not paired observations. Man-Whitney could be what I want, though.

Comment: Yes, read the help file for `wilcox.test`. The default is `paired = FALSE` which is going to be a Mann-Whitney for two vector inputs.